# ¿Cómo podría validar el contenido HTML de un textarea vía PHP o Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, validación

Yo tengo un formulario que recoge varios datos para luego insertarlos en una base de datos al presionar un botón. El formulario se ejecuta en un área privada de mi página web, y lo utilizo para alimentar contenido en una base de datos alojada en el mismo hosting del dominio (no es para uso de terceros).

El código funciona bien, pero tengo una pequeña dificultad:

En los elementos del formulario hay un textarea como este:

```
<textarea name="txtContenido" id="txt_Contenido" rows="20" cols="170" class="insertar"></textarea>
```

Dentro de él yo debo introducir contenido con etiquetas HTML, como este:

`<p>>El Evangelio de San Marcos (1,21-28) nos muestra a Jesús que enseña “<i>como quien tiene autoridad</i>”. Se trata de una enseñanza nueva, y la novedad de Cristo es precisamente el don de la autoridad recibido del Padre. Ante las enseñanzas de los escribas y doctores de la ley, que también decían la verdad, la gente pensaba en otra cosa, porque lo que decían no llegaba al corazón: enseñaban desde la cátedra, pero no se interesaban por la gente. En cambio, la enseñanza de Jesús provoca asombro, movimiento del corazón, porque lo que da autoridad es precisamente la cercanía, y Jesús se acercaba a la gente, y por eso comprendía sus problemas, dolores y pecados. Porque era cercano, comprendía; y acogía, curaba y enseñaba con cercanía. Lo que a un pastor le da autoridad o despierta la autoridad que le dio el Padre, es la cercanía: cercanía a Dios en la oración –un pastor que no reza, un pastor que no busca a Dios está perdido– y la cercanía a la gente. El pastor separado de la gente no llega a la gente. Cercanía, esa doble cercanía. Esa es la unción del pastor que se conmueve ante el don de Dios en la oración, y se puede conmover ante los pecados, problemas y enfermedades de la gente: ¡deja que el pastor se conmueva! <br /><br />Los escribas habían perdido la capacidad de conmoverse porque no eran cercanos ni a la gente ni a Dios. Y cuando se pierde la cercanía, el pastor acaba en la incoherencia de vida. Jesús es claro en esto: “<i>Haced lo que dicen</i>” –dicen la verdad– “<i>pero no lo que hacen</i>”. La doble vida. Qué feo ver pastores de doble vida: es una herida en la Iglesia. Los pastores enfermos, que han perdido la autoridad y llevan esa doble vida. Hay muchos modos de llevar una doble vida: pero es doble… Y Jesús es muy fuerte con ellos. No solo dice a la gente que les escuchen, sino que no hagan lo que hacen. Y a ellos, ¿qué les dice? “<i>Sois como sepulcros blanqueados</i>”: hermosísimos en la doctrina, por fuera, pero dentro, podredumbre. Ese es el final del pastor que no tiene cercanía con Dios en la oración ni con la gente en la compasión. <br /><br />En la Primera Lectura están las figuras de Ana, que reza al Señor para tener un hijo varón, y del sacerdote, el viejo Elí, que era débil, había perdido la cercanía, a Dios y a la gente, y pensó que Ana estaba borracha. Ella, en cambio, rezaba en su corazón, moviendo solo los labios. Fue ella la que explicó a Elí que estaba amargada y que “<i>si he estado hablando hasta ahora, ha sido de pura congoja y aflicción</i>”. Y mientras ella hablaba, Elí fue capaz de acercarse a aquel corazón, hasta decirle que se fuera en paz: “<i>Que el Dios de Israel te conceda lo que le has pedido</i>”. Se dio cuenta que se había equivocado, e hizo salir de su corazón la bendición y la profecía, porque luego Ana dio a luz a Samuel. <br /><br />Yo diría a los pastores que han llevado una vida separados de Dios y del pueblo, de la gente: “No perdáis la esperanza. Siempre hay una posibilidad. A este le fue suficiente mirar, acercarse a una mujer, escucharla y despertó su autoridad para bendecir y profetizar; esa profecía se cumplió y el hijo le nació a la mujer”. La autoridad, don de Dios: solo viene de Él, y Jesús la da a los suyos. Autoridad al hablar, que viene de la cercanía con Dios y con la gente, siempre las dos juntas. Autoridad que es coherencia, no doble vida. Autoridad, y si un pastor la pierde, al menos que no pierda la esperanza, como Elí: siempre hay tiempo para acercarse y despertar la autoridad y la profecía.</p>`

Lo que quiero encontrar es alguna forma de validar ese contenido antes de introducirlo, de forma que me detecte si hay algún error y me impida la inserción.

Por ejemplo al principio, sobraría un cierre de la etiqueta `<p>>`, quisiera poder detectar ese tipo de cosas, así como errores más graves, como etiquetas que se abran y no se cierren, o etiquetas de cierre sin apertura.

¿Habría alguna forma de hacer eso, sea por medio de PHP o de Javascript?

Comment: Yo te aconsejaría usar algún `WYSIWYG ` así le facilitas al usuario que pueda dar formato al texto y de paso te aseguras que las etiquetas siempre están bien cerradas

Comment: Gracias @JoseJavierSegura. He aclarado ese detalle al principio de la pregunta. Es un formulario para mi uso solamente, que empleo para alimentar una base de datos con ese contenido, por eso busco una solución sencilla de validación sin perderme en demasiados detalles de cara a otros futuros usuarios. El contenido ya viene preparado en HTML, sólo quiero que me detecte cuando haya errores.

Comment: Implementarlo desde luego sería muy entretenido, pero podrías pegar tu código [aquí](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) y ahorrarte el trabajo

Answer (score 4):

Un "workaround" sencillo es incluir el texto como contenido HTML de un elemento y comprobar que el contenido que finalmente se asigna coincide con el texto original:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('txt_Contenido');
var checkDiv = document.createElement('div');
checkDiv.innerHTML = txt.value;
console.log(checkDiv.innerHTML === txt.value
  ? 'El código HTML es válido'
  : 'El código HTML contiene errores');
```

```html
<textarea name="txtContenido" id="txt_Contenido" rows="20" cols="170" class="insertar">
<p>>El Evangelio de San Marcos (1,21-28) nos muestra a Jesús que enseña “<i>como quien tiene autoridad</i>”. Se trata de una enseñanza nueva, y la novedad de Cristo es precisamente el don de la autoridad recibido del Padre. Ante las enseñanzas de los escribas y doctores de la ley, que también decían la verdad, la gente pensaba en otra cosa, porque lo que decían no llegaba al corazón: enseñaban desde la cátedra, pero no se interesaban por la gente. En cambio, la enseñanza de Jesús provoca asombro, movimiento del corazón, porque lo que da autoridad es precisamente la cercanía, y Jesús se acercaba a la gente, y por eso comprendía sus problemas, dolores y pecados. Porque era cercano, comprendía; y acogía, curaba y enseñaba con cercanía. Lo que a un pastor le da autoridad o despierta la autoridad que le dio el Padre, es la cercanía: cercanía a Dios en la oración –un pastor que no reza, un pastor que no busca a Dios está perdido– y la cercanía a la gente. El pastor separado de la gente no llega a la gente. Cercanía, esa doble cercanía. Esa es la unción del pastor que se conmueve ante el don de Dios en la oración, y se puede conmover ante los pecados, problemas y enfermedades de la gente: ¡deja que el pastor se conmueva! <br /><br />Los escribas habían perdido la capacidad de conmoverse porque no eran cercanos ni a la gente ni a Dios. Y cuando se pierde la cercanía, el pastor acaba en la incoherencia de vida. Jesús es claro en esto: “<i>Haced lo que dicen</i>” –dicen la verdad– “<i>pero no lo que hacen</i>”. La doble vida. Qué feo ver pastores de doble vida: es una herida en la Iglesia. Los pastores enfermos, que han perdido la autoridad y llevan esa doble vida. Hay muchos modos de llevar una doble vida: pero es doble… Y Jesús es muy fuerte con ellos. No solo dice a la gente que les escuchen, sino que no hagan lo que hacen. Y a ellos, ¿qué les dice? “<i>Sois como sepulcros blanqueados</i>”: hermosísimos en la doctrina, por fuera, pero dentro, podredumbre. Ese es el final del pastor que no tiene cercanía con Dios en la oración ni con la gente en la compasión. <br /><br />En la Primera Lectura están las figuras de Ana, que reza al Señor para tener un hijo varón, y del sacerdote, el viejo Elí, que era débil, había perdido la cercanía, a Dios y a la gente, y pensó que Ana estaba borracha. Ella, en cambio, rezaba en su corazón, moviendo solo los labios. Fue ella la que explicó a Elí que estaba amargada y que “<i>si he estado hablando hasta ahora, ha sido de pura congoja y aflicción</i>”. Y mientras ella hablaba, Elí fue capaz de acercarse a aquel corazón, hasta decirle que se fuera en paz: “<i>Que el Dios de Israel te conceda lo que le has pedido</i>”. Se dio cuenta que se había equivocado, e hizo salir de su corazón la bendición y la profecía, porque luego Ana dio a luz a Samuel. <br /><br />Yo diría a los pastores que han llevado una vida separados de Dios y del pueblo, de la gente: “No perdáis la esperanza. Siempre hay una posibilidad. A este le fue suficiente mirar, acercarse a una mujer, escucharla y despertó su autoridad para bendecir y profetizar; esa profecía se cumplió y el hijo le nació a la mujer”. La autoridad, don de Dios: solo viene de Él, y Jesús la da a los suyos. Autoridad al hablar, que viene de la cercanía con Dios y con la gente, siempre las dos juntas. Autoridad que es coherencia, no doble vida. Autoridad, y si un pastor la pierde, al menos que no pierda la esperanza, como Elí: siempre hay tiempo para acercarse y despertar la autoridad y la profecía.</p>
</textarea>
```

Ten en cuenta que en este caso el código también detectaría como errores espacios de más, etiquetas en mayúsculas o la sintaxis xhtml (como el cierre de etiquetas en los elementos 'br' en tu caso, es decir utilizar `<br />` en lugar de `<br>`)

Algunos de estos problemas podrías eliminarlos de forma sencilla quitando espacios y pasando el texto a minúsculas antes de compararlo.

Otros casos como el de las etiquetas `br` deberías tratarlos por separado:

```js
function transform(cod1){
  // Elimina espacios
  var transformed = cod1.replace(/\s/g, '');
  // Paso a minúsculas
  transformed = transformed.toLowerCase();
  // Normaliza etiquetas <br>
  transformed = transformed.replace(/<br[/]>/g, '<br>');
  return transformed;
}

var txt = document.getElementById('txt_Contenido');
var checkDiv = document.createElement('div');
checkDiv.innerHTML = txt.value;
console.log(
  transform(checkDiv.innerHTML) === transform(txt.value)
  ? 'El código HTML es válido'
  : 'El código HTML contiene errores');
```

```html
<textarea name="txtContenido" id="txt_Contenido" rows="20" cols="170" class="insertar">
<p>El Evangelio de San Marcos (1,21-28) nos muestra a Jesús que enseña “<i>como quien tiene autoridad</i>”. Se trata de una enseñanza nueva, y la novedad de Cristo es precisamente el don de la autoridad recibido del Padre. Ante las enseñanzas de los escribas y doctores de la ley, que también decían la verdad, la gente pensaba en otra cosa, porque lo que decían no llegaba al corazón: enseñaban desde la cátedra, pero no se interesaban por la gente. En cambio, la enseñanza de Jesús provoca asombro, movimiento del corazón, porque lo que da autoridad es precisamente la cercanía, y Jesús se acercaba a la gente, y por eso comprendía sus problemas, dolores y pecados. Porque era cercano, comprendía; y acogía, curaba y enseñaba con cercanía. Lo que a un pastor le da autoridad o despierta la autoridad que le dio el Padre, es la cercanía: cercanía a Dios en la oración –un pastor que no reza, un pastor que no busca a Dios está perdido– y la cercanía a la gente. El pastor separado de la gente no llega a la gente. Cercanía, esa doble cercanía. Esa es la unción del pastor que se conmueve ante el don de Dios en la oración, y se puede conmover ante los pecados, problemas y enfermedades de la gente: ¡deja que el pastor se conmueva! <BR><BR >Los escribas habían perdido la capacidad de conmoverse porque no eran cercanos ni a la gente ni a Dios. Y cuando se pierde la cercanía, el pastor acaba en la incoherencia de vida. Jesús es claro en esto: “<i>Haced lo que dicen</i>” –dicen la verdad– “<i>pero no lo que hacen</i>”. La doble vida. Qué feo ver pastores de doble vida: es una herida en la Iglesia. Los pastores enfermos, que han perdido la autoridad y llevan esa doble vida. Hay muchos modos de llevar una doble vida: pero es doble… Y Jesús es muy fuerte con ellos. No solo dice a la gente que les escuchen, sino que no hagan lo que hacen. Y a ellos, ¿qué les dice? “<i>Sois como sepulcros blanqueados</i>”: hermosísimos en la doctrina, por fuera, pero dentro, podredumbre. Ese es el final del pastor que no tiene cercanía con Dios en la oración ni con la gente en la compasión. <br /><br />En la Primera Lectura están las figuras de Ana, que reza al Señor para tener un hijo varón, y del sacerdote, el viejo Elí, que era débil, había perdido la cercanía, a Dios y a la gente, y pensó que Ana estaba borracha. Ella, en cambio, rezaba en su corazón, moviendo solo los labios. Fue ella la que explicó a Elí que estaba amargada y que “<i>si he estado hablando hasta ahora, ha sido de pura congoja y aflicción</i>”. Y mientras ella hablaba, Elí fue capaz de acercarse a aquel corazón, hasta decirle que se fuera en paz: “<i>Que el Dios de Israel te conceda lo que le has pedido</i>”. Se dio cuenta que se había equivocado, e hizo salir de su corazón la bendición y la profecía, porque luego Ana dio a luz a Samuel. <br><br>Yo diría a los pastores que han llevado una vida separados de Dios y del pueblo, de la gente: “No perdáis la esperanza. Siempre hay una posibilidad. A este le fue suficiente mirar, acercarse a una mujer, escucharla y despertó su autoridad para bendecir y profetizar; esa profecía se cumplió y el hijo le nació a la mujer”. La autoridad, don de Dios: solo viene de Él, y Jesús la da a los suyos. Autoridad al hablar, que viene de la cercanía con Dios y con la gente, siempre las dos juntas. Autoridad que es coherencia, no doble vida. Autoridad, y si un pastor la pierde, al menos que no pierda la esperanza, como Elí: siempre hay tiempo para acercarse y despertar la autoridad y la profecía.</p>
</textarea>
```

Aunque de esta forma podrías obtener algún falso positivo con espacios fuera de lugar como: `<img s rc="http://...`

Comment: Interesante, justamente necesito algo así, sencillo. Yo ya tengo una función para *limpiar* el texto, suprimiendo los múltiples espacios en blanco y buscando codificaciones extrañas que pudiera haber. Lo de los `<br />` me gustaría guardarlos... podría hacer un truco jugando con el contenido para mantenerlos, pero ¿sabes si se puede hacer una excepción con esa etiqueta en específico a la hora de validar?

Comment: Para las etiquetas `br` podrías normalizarlas antes de comparar los textos. He modificado el segundo ejemplo para cubrir este caso.

Answer (score 2):

En complemento a la [respuesta de Asier](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130056/16597).

### Javascript

Al utilizar `DOMElement.innerHTML = txt`, lo que sucederá es que el [`Motor de análisis HTML`](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#HTML_Parser) del navegador va a [*arreglar el texto introducido para mostrarlo*](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Browsers_error_tolerance)

Teniendo esto en cuenta, en lugar de solo validar y mostrar un error si estos no coinciden, podrías usar esto a tu favor y *corregir* el texto introducido.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function getHTML(text) {
  let el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = text;
  return el.innerHTML;
}

function validarHTML() {
  let textarea = document.getElementById('txt_Contenido');
  let html = getHTML(textarea.value);

  document.getElementById('txt_invalid')
    .style.display = textarea.value != html ? 'block' : 'none';
}

// Validar `HTML` introducido
document.getElementById('txt_Contenido').addEventListener('input', validarHTML);

// Fix `HTML`
document.getElementById('txt_fix').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let textarea = document.getElementById('txt_Contenido');
  let html = getHTML(textarea.value);
  textarea.value = html;
  
  validarHTML();
});

// Disparamos el evento para validar
validarHTML();
```

```css
#txt_invalid {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="txtContenido" id="txt_Contenido" rows="10" cols="80" class="insertar">
<p>>El Evangelio de San Marcos (1,21-28) nos muestra a Jesús que enseña “<i>como quien tiene autoridad</i>”. Se trata de una enseñanza nueva, y la novedad de Cristo es precisamente el don de la autoridad recibido del Padre. Ante las enseñanzas de los escribas y doctores de la ley, que también decían la verdad, la gente pensaba en otra cosa, porque lo que decían no llegaba al corazón: enseñaban desde la cátedra, pero no se interesaban por la gente. En cambio, la enseñanza de Jesús provoca asombro, movimiento del corazón, porque lo que da autoridad es precisamente la cercanía, y Jesús se acercaba a la gente, y por eso comprendía sus problemas, dolores y pecados. Porque era cercano, comprendía; y acogía, curaba y enseñaba con cercanía. Lo que a un pastor le da autoridad o despierta la autoridad que le dio el Padre, es la cercanía: cercanía a Dios en la oración –un pastor que no reza, un pastor que no busca a Dios está perdido– y la cercanía a la gente. El pastor separado de la gente no llega a la gente. Cercanía, esa doble cercanía. Esa es la unción del pastor que se conmueve ante el don de Dios en la oración, y se puede conmover ante los pecados, problemas y enfermedades de la gente: ¡deja que el pastor se conmueva! <BR><BR >Los escribas habían perdido la capacidad de conmoverse porque no eran cercanos ni a la gente ni a Dios. Y cuando se pierde la cercanía, el pastor acaba en la incoherencia de vida. Jesús es claro en esto: “<i>Haced lo que dicen</i>” –dicen la verdad– “<i>pero no lo que hacen</i>”. La doble vida. Qué feo ver pastores de doble vida: es una herida en la Iglesia. Los pastores enfermos, que han perdido la autoridad y llevan esa doble vida. Hay muchos modos de llevar una doble vida: pero es doble… Y Jesús es muy fuerte con ellos. No solo dice a la gente que les escuchen, sino que no hagan lo que hacen. Y a ellos, ¿qué les dice? “<i>Sois como sepulcros blanqueados</i>”: hermosísimos en la doctrina, por fuera, pero dentro, podredumbre. Ese es el final del pastor que no tiene cercanía con Dios en la oración ni con la gente en la compasión. <br /><br />En la Primera Lectura están las figuras de Ana, que reza al Señor para tener un hijo varón, y del sacerdote, el viejo Elí, que era débil, había perdido la cercanía, a Dios y a la gente, y pensó que Ana estaba borracha. Ella, en cambio, rezaba en su corazón, moviendo solo los labios. Fue ella la que explicó a Elí que estaba amargada y que “<i>si he estado hablando hasta ahora, ha sido de pura congoja y aflicción</i>”. Y mientras ella hablaba, Elí fue capaz de acercarse a aquel corazón, hasta decirle que se fuera en paz: “<i>Que el Dios de Israel te conceda lo que le has pedido</i>”. Se dio cuenta que se había equivocado, e hizo salir de su corazón la bendición y la profecía, porque luego Ana dio a luz a Samuel. <br><br>Yo diría a los pastores que han llevado una vida separados de Dios y del pueblo, de la gente: “No perdáis la esperanza. Siempre hay una posibilidad. A este le fue suficiente mirar, acercarse a una mujer, escucharla y despertó su autoridad para bendecir y profetizar; esa profecía se cumplió y el hijo le nació a la mujer”. La autoridad, don de Dios: solo viene de Él, y Jesús la da a los suyos. Autoridad al hablar, que viene de la cercanía con Dios y con la gente, siempre las dos juntas. Autoridad que es coherencia, no doble vida. Autoridad, y si un pastor la pierde, al menos que no pierda la esperanza, como Elí: siempre hay tiempo para acercarse y despertar la autoridad y la profecía.</p>
</textarea>
<div id="txt_invalid">
  HTML inválido
  <button id="txt_fix">Corregir!</button>
</div>
```

---

### PHP

Con `PHP`, y siguiendo la misma línea, podrías resolverlo usando:

#### Opción 1: [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

```
<?php
$text = "<p>>El Evangelio de San Marcos (1,21-28) nos muestra a Jesús que enseña “<i>como quien tiene autoridad</i>”. Se trata de una enseñanza nueva, y la novedad de Cristo es precisamente el don de la autoridad recibido del Padre. Ante las enseñanzas de los escribas y doctores de la ley, que también decían la verdad, la gente pensaba en otra cosa, porque lo que decían no llegaba al corazón: enseñaban desde la cátedra, pero no se interesaban por la gente. En cambio, la enseñanza de Jesús provoca asombro, movimiento del corazón, porque lo que da autoridad es precisamente la cercanía, y Jesús se acercaba a la gente, y por eso comprendía sus problemas, dolores y pecados. Porque era cercano, comprendía; y acogía, curaba y enseñaba con cercanía. Lo que a un pastor le da autoridad o despierta la autoridad que le dio el Padre, es la cercanía: cercanía a Dios en la oración –un pastor que no reza, un pastor que no busca a Dios está perdido– y la cercanía a la gente. El pastor separado de la gente no llega a la gente. Cercanía, esa doble cercanía. Esa es la unción del pastor que se conmueve ante el don de Dios en la oración, y se puede conmover ante los pecados, problemas y enfermedades de la gente: ¡deja que el pastor se conmueva! <br /><br />Los escribas habían perdido la capacidad de conmoverse porque no eran cercanos ni a la gente ni a Dios. Y cuando se pierde la cercanía, el pastor acaba en la incoherencia de vida. Jesús es claro en esto: “<i>Haced lo que dicen</i>” –dicen la verdad– “<i>pero no lo que hacen</i>”. La doble vida. Qué feo ver pastores de doble vida: es una herida en la Iglesia. Los pastores enfermos, que han perdido la autoridad y llevan esa doble vida. Hay muchos modos de llevar una doble vida: pero es doble… Y Jesús es muy fuerte con ellos. No solo dice a la gente que les escuchen, sino que no hagan lo que hacen. Y a ellos, ¿qué les dice? “<i>Sois como sepulcros blanqueados</i>”: hermosísimos en la doctrina, por fuera, pero dentro, podredumbre. Ese es el final del pastor que no tiene cercanía con Dios en la oración ni con la gente en la compasión. <br /><br />En la Primera Lectura están las figuras de Ana, que reza al Señor para tener un hijo varón, y del sacerdote, el viejo Elí, que era débil, había perdido la cercanía, a Dios y a la gente, y pensó que Ana estaba borracha. Ella, en cambio, rezaba en su corazón, moviendo solo los labios. Fue ella la que explicó a Elí que estaba amargada y que “<i>si he estado hablando hasta ahora, ha sido de pura congoja y aflicción</i>”. Y mientras ella hablaba, Elí fue capaz de acercarse a aquel corazón, hasta decirle que se fuera en paz: “<i>Que el Dios de Israel te conceda lo que le has pedido</i>”. Se dio cuenta que se había equivocado, e hizo salir de su corazón la bendición y la profecía, porque luego Ana dio a luz a Samuel. <br /><br />Yo diría a los pastores que han llevado una vida separados de Dios y del pueblo, de la gente: “No perdáis la esperanza. Siempre hay una posibilidad. A este le fue suficiente mirar, acercarse a una mujer, escucharla y despertó su autoridad para bendecir y profetizar; esa profecía se cumplió y el hijo le nació a la mujer”. La autoridad, don de Dios: solo viene de Él, y Jesús la da a los suyos. Autoridad al hablar, que viene de la cercanía con Dios y con la gente, siempre las dos juntas. Autoridad que es coherencia, no doble vida. Autoridad, y si un pastor la pierde, al menos que no pierda la esperanza, como Elí: siempre hay tiempo para acercarse y despertar la autoridad y la profecía.</p>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$error = $doc->loadHTML($text);
if ($error) {
    $isValid = false;
} else {
    $htmlFixed = $doc->saveHTML();
    $isValid = $htmlFixed == $text;
}
```

#### Opción 2: [tidy::repairString](http://php.net/manual/es/tidy.repairstring.php)

```
<?php
$text = "<p>>El Evangelio de San Marcos (1,21-28) nos muestra a Jesús que enseña “<i>como quien tiene autoridad</i>”. Se trata de una enseñanza nueva, y la novedad de Cristo es precisamente el don de la autoridad recibido del Padre. Ante las enseñanzas de los escribas y doctores de la ley, que también decían la verdad, la gente pensaba en otra cosa, porque lo que decían no llegaba al corazón: enseñaban desde la cátedra, pero no se interesaban por la gente. En cambio, la enseñanza de Jesús provoca asombro, movimiento del corazón, porque lo que da autoridad es precisamente la cercanía, y Jesús se acercaba a la gente, y por eso comprendía sus problemas, dolores y pecados. Porque era cercano, comprendía; y acogía, curaba y enseñaba con cercanía. Lo que a un pastor le da autoridad o despierta la autoridad que le dio el Padre, es la cercanía: cercanía a Dios en la oración –un pastor que no reza, un pastor que no busca a Dios está perdido– y la cercanía a la gente. El pastor separado de la gente no llega a la gente. Cercanía, esa doble cercanía. Esa es la unción del pastor que se conmueve ante el don de Dios en la oración, y se puede conmover ante los pecados, problemas y enfermedades de la gente: ¡deja que el pastor se conmueva! <br /><br />Los escribas habían perdido la capacidad de conmoverse porque no eran cercanos ni a la gente ni a Dios. Y cuando se pierde la cercanía, el pastor acaba en la incoherencia de vida. Jesús es claro en esto: “<i>Haced lo que dicen</i>” –dicen la verdad– “<i>pero no lo que hacen</i>”. La doble vida. Qué feo ver pastores de doble vida: es una herida en la Iglesia. Los pastores enfermos, que han perdido la autoridad y llevan esa doble vida. Hay muchos modos de llevar una doble vida: pero es doble… Y Jesús es muy fuerte con ellos. No solo dice a la gente que les escuchen, sino que no hagan lo que hacen. Y a ellos, ¿qué les dice? “<i>Sois como sepulcros blanqueados</i>”: hermosísimos en la doctrina, por fuera, pero dentro, podredumbre. Ese es el final del pastor que no tiene cercanía con Dios en la oración ni con la gente en la compasión. <br /><br />En la Primera Lectura están las figuras de Ana, que reza al Señor para tener un hijo varón, y del sacerdote, el viejo Elí, que era débil, había perdido la cercanía, a Dios y a la gente, y pensó que Ana estaba borracha. Ella, en cambio, rezaba en su corazón, moviendo solo los labios. Fue ella la que explicó a Elí que estaba amargada y que “<i>si he estado hablando hasta ahora, ha sido de pura congoja y aflicción</i>”. Y mientras ella hablaba, Elí fue capaz de acercarse a aquel corazón, hasta decirle que se fuera en paz: “<i>Que el Dios de Israel te conceda lo que le has pedido</i>”. Se dio cuenta que se había equivocado, e hizo salir de su corazón la bendición y la profecía, porque luego Ana dio a luz a Samuel. <br /><br />Yo diría a los pastores que han llevado una vida separados de Dios y del pueblo, de la gente: “No perdáis la esperanza. Siempre hay una posibilidad. A este le fue suficiente mirar, acercarse a una mujer, escucharla y despertó su autoridad para bendecir y profetizar; esa profecía se cumplió y el hijo le nació a la mujer”. La autoridad, don de Dios: solo viene de Él, y Jesús la da a los suyos. Autoridad al hablar, que viene de la cercanía con Dios y con la gente, siempre las dos juntas. Autoridad que es coherencia, no doble vida. Autoridad, y si un pastor la pierde, al menos que no pierda la esperanza, como Elí: siempre hay tiempo para acercarse y despertar la autoridad y la profecía.</p>";
$tidy = new tidy();
$htmlFixed = $tidy->repairString($text);
$isValid = $htmlFixed == $text;
```

Comment: Marcos, pero ¿por qué me cambia el `>` de más por `&gt;`? ¿Eso significa que según los caracteres erróneos que haya los sustituirá por otros?

Comment: @A.Cedano, el cambio lo hace automáticamente el `HTML Parser`. Esa decisión la toma debido a que detecta que el `>` no es el cierre de un `tag` (_sobra_), por lo que para generar un texto HTML válido, debe traducirlo a su [`equivalente como entidad HTML`](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)